# CasperJs doesn't execute completely from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, linux, stdout, casperjs

Sample CasperJs test:

```
casper.test.begin('Hello, Test!', 1, function(test) {
    test.assert(true);
    test.done();
});
```

Result of Linux command execution:

```
# casperjs test /bin/casper-test.js
Test file: /bin/casper-test.js
# Hello, Test!
PASS Subject is strictly true
PASS Hello, Test! (1 test)
PASS 1 test executed in 0.026s, 1 passed, 0 failed, 0 dubious, 0 skipped.
```

Result of PHP:

```
<?php
echo exec('casperjs test /path/to/casper-test.js');
?>
[37;42;1mPASS 1 test executed in 0.024s, 1 passed, 0 failed, 0 dubious, 0 skipped. [0m
```

As you see it only shows the last line of Linux command (correct) result.
Any ideas?

Comment: Be sure to accept an answer by clicking the little checkbox if it is correct and optionally up vote, thank you!

Comment: @Clayton Smith For sure!Thank you for your complete answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the documentation for `exec`:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

> string exec ( string $command [, array &$output [, int &$return_var ]] )

To capture all the output, you should be able to do something like this:

```
exec('casperjs test /path/to/casper-test.js 2>&1', $output, $return_var);
var_dump($output);
var_dump($return_var);
```

Appending `2>&1` to your command will redirect the `STDERR` and `STDOUT` and capture it in the `$output` variable.

Also, I noticed the output appears to be trying to colorize it for output on the shell, that's what the `[37;42;` string is. According to the docs, it looks like you can add `--no-colors` to your command to disable the colorized output:

```
casperjs test --no-colors  /path/to/casper-test.js 2>&1
```